# Help drawing a more sophisticated right triangle with tikz or something else

Tags: tikz-pgf, draw

I am preparing a geometry note file for my students and I am trying to reproduce a figure I saw on Wikipedia in the proof of the Pythagorean theorem. Here is the figure
[image]

I can draw a right triangle with tikz after some trial and error, but I do not know how to color the interiors of the shapes, label the vertices, label the angles as nicely as shown in the figure below, drop a perpendicular, and mark the angles with arcs or a square for a right angle as in H and C vertices. I am a math teacher by profession and my computer and TeX proficiency are minimal. I would certainly appreciate any help with this. My aim is to create my own figures so as not to plagiarize. I thank all helpers.

Edit: here is my code for a right triangle

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.25]

\coordinate (A) at (-1.5cm,-1.cm);
\coordinate (C) at (1.5cm,-1.0cm);
\coordinate (B) at (1.5cm,1.0cm);
\draw (A) --  (B) --  (C) -- (A);

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  Could you post the code for your right triangle?  That would give us something to start from.

Comment: You might want to try [geogebra classic](https://www.geogebra.org/classic), it can export tikz code

Comment: @Teepeemm thank you for your suggestion, I have added my code

Comment: Since the two interior triangles are similar (to each other and the outer triangle) it would help to use easily rotated triangles, like 3-4-5 or 30-60-90 (1-2-\sqrt{3}).

Comment: You seem to be working your way through proofs of Pythagoras' theorem.  Let me know when you get to the *correct* one, and I can provide the code for it as seen in https://loopspace.mathforge.org/CountingOnMyFingers/FavouriteProof/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I propose this solution with the `pst-eucl` module of `pstricks`, which can mimick constructions of plane geometry:

```
\documentclass[border=6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[x11names,svgnames]{xcolor}%
\usepackage{pst-eucl}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-1,-1)(7,5)
\psset{PointSymbol=none, linejoin=1,CodeFigStyle=solid, CodeFigColor=black}
\pstTriangle[PosAngle={120,-130,-30}](0,4){A}(0,0){C}(6,0){B}
\pstProjection[CodeFig]{B}{A}{C}[H]\psline(C)(H)
\pspolygon*[linecolor=LightSteelBlue2!90](B)(H)(C)
\pspolygon*[linecolor=YellowGreen!30](C)(H)(A)
\psset{linewidth=0.6pt}
\psline(H)(A)(C)(H)(B)(C)
\psset{MarkAngleRadius=0.8, RightAngleSize=0.25, LabelSep=0.6}%, LabelSep=-0.2cm}
\pstMarkAngle{H}{C}{A}{$\theta$} \pstMarkAngle{B}{C}{H}{}\pstMarkAngle{B}{C}{H}{}
\pstMarkAngle{H}{B}{C}{$\theta$}
\pstMarkAngle{C}{A}{H}{}
\psset{MarkAngleRadius=0.6} 
\pstMarkAngle{B}{C}{H}{}
\pstMarkAngle{C}{A}{H}{}
\pstRightAngle{B}{C}{A} \pstRightAngle{C}{H}{A}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you so much. Small question if I may ask. How would I also mark the HCB angle with 90-\theta for maximum clarity?

Comment: You may, of course: we're here to help. Actually, it is already marked  with the smaller `\MarkAngleRadius` (I copied your posted image with the pstricks tools). But if you think the larger is confusional, you may use colour the markings for this angle and for the corresponding angle CAH, for instance. Or colour the theta angles. To colour the angles, e.g. in red, use`\pstMarkAngle[linecolor=red]{…}`.

Comment: thank you so kindly, after reading and learning your code, I copied it into my document and it is giving several errors. It does not seem to be recognizing anything in the pspicture environment. I loaded the two packages in the order you gave, in addition to my other used packages. Could you please advise? Thank you.

Comment: @kroner: Which compiler did you use?

Comment: I use Texstudio with Miktex on a Windows 10 machine

Comment: That doesn't tell *how* you compiled. The simplest  is to use `xelatex` with the `--shell-escape` switch

Comment: thank you, how would I do that on Texstudio?

Comment: In the `Options` menu, select `Configure TeX Studio`; you'll obtain a menu   with the default configuration of all compilers. Simply add --shell-escape to the defaults switches. You also might compile the code I propose, compile it as I said, and include the resulting .pdf in your main file via `\includegraphics`. This would shorten the compilation time each time you add or modify something to your main file.

Answer (score 5):

With the help of `quotes` and `angles` libraries, it's not difficult to get it.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, angles, quotes, backgrounds}
    
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw (0,0) node[below left] {$C$} coordinate (C) -- (0,3) node[above left] {$A$} coordinate (A) -- (5,0) node[below right] {$B$} coordinate (B)--cycle;
\draw (C)--($(A)!(C)!(B)$) coordinate (H) node[above right]{$H$};

\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\fill[blue!30] (B)--(C)--(H)--cycle;
\fill[green!30] (A)--(C)--(H)--cycle;
\end{scope}

\draw pic[draw] {angle=C--A--H} pic[draw, angle radius=4mm] {angle=C--A--H};
\draw pic["$\theta$",draw, angle radius=7mm, angle eccentricity=.8] {angle=H--B--C};
\draw pic["$\theta$",draw, angle radius=8mm, angle eccentricity=.8] {angle=H--C--A};
\draw pic[draw, angle radius=8mm] {angle=B--C--A}  pic[draw, angle radius=7mm] {angle=B--C--H};

\draw pic[draw, angle radius=3mm] {right angle=B--C--A};
\draw pic[draw, angle radius=3mm] {right angle=C--H--A};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This uses a 3-4-5 triangle.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate (C) at (0,3);
\coordinate (B) at (4,0);
\coordinate (D) at ($(C)!{9/25}!(B)$);% see derivation below
\draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle;
\draw (A) -- (D);
\path pic [draw,angle radius=2mm] {right angle = C--A--B}
      pic [draw,angle radius=2mm] {right angle = A--D--B};
\fill[red, opacity=0.5] (A) -- (B) -- (D);
\fill[blue, opacity=0.5] (A) -- (C) -- (D);
\node[below left] at (A) {A};
\node[below right] at (B) {B};
\node[above left] at (C) {C};
\node[above right] at (D) {D};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

[image: derivation]